# what will ¬ do in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, background-process

While wanting to start `gitg` as backgrounded through writing  `gitg &` I accidentally typed `gitg ¬`. This did not cause an error, instead I got with a later command in the same terminal (translated): `[1]+  Finished                  gitg`

I am not sure if the two things were related. Anyway: Does anybody know what `<programm> ¬` will do?

Comment: under **¬** you mean symbol or hitting return (enter)

Comment: @MolbOrg I mean I accidentally hit the strange ¬ symbol (of cause I send the command with enter, afterwards)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case it printed previous backgrounded job result

```
[xxx@host]$ /usr/bin/echo test>/dev/null & <Enter>
[1] 4559
[xxx@host]$ <Enter>
[1]+  Done                    /usr/bin/echo test > /dev/null
```

Comment: This is correct - at least about what happened the first time - the process *was* backgrounded and the shell later reported when it quit.

Comment: @mike actually process is gone long before second enter, which in that case acts like NOP, and after second command bash printed result of previous command. First second - i feel i missing point - can you clear it ?)

Comment: His `gitg` actually *did* `bg` is all i was saying. Whether or not that would happen again with the little handgun character i dont know, but it did the first time.

Comment: @mike yes, sure - exactly)

Comment: Actually I repeated the `gitg &` command after realizing I used the wrong command. So that would be the explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

It will do nothing as far as I know. The `¬` will just be treated as an argument to the command:

```
$ ls ¬
ls: cannot access ¬: No such file or directory
```